# How not use temp tablespace

Tags: oracle-11g, tablespaces

How to not use the temp tablespace in oracle?

I have something like this:

```
set timing on;
create table export_table
tablespace tbspace1
noparallel
nomonitoring
as
select  /*+ full(cs) full(soi_aux) parallel(cs, 30) parallel(soi_aux, 30)*/
    distinct
    soi_aux.field1,
    soi_aux.field2
from
    export_table2 cs,
    big_table soi_aux
where
    cs.*** = soi_aux.***
    and soi_aux.****** = cs.***
    and soi_aux.***** = '*****'
    and soi_aux.****** = '*******';
```

However big_table has 450GB space, my Temp Tablespace has 140GB.

When I execute this, I get this error:

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
```

Is there anyway to avoid write in Temp tablespace, or distribute it for others tablespaces?

Note: I can't change the tablespace size.

EDIT:

```
 - What is the query plan with and without the hints?
```

Later I can post the explain plan. Without hints, I go full for export_table2 and indexed big_table, although a single query with índex on big_table it takes always 2 or 3 seconds.

```
 - How big will the table that you create be?
```

~950k lines

```
 - Do you need the distinct?
```

Yes, I can go for order by+rownum=1 too.

```
 - How big is the data set before you distinct it?
```

Big table: 650 millions lines, export_table2 950k

```
- How selective are the predicates that you've obfuscated?
```

Both indexed (single)

```
 - How much of that 140 GB are other sessions using?
```

0

Comment: Full scans with 30 parallel workers is going to use a ton of TEMP space for sorting.  What is the query plan with and without the hints?  How big will the table that you create be?  Do you need the distinct?  How big is the data set before you distinct it?  How selective are the predicates that you've obfuscated?  How much of that 140 GB are other sessions using?

Comment: @JustinCave I edited my question.

Comment: I'm more of a Sql Server person and my suggestion is not 'set theory', but could you use a cursor to read each row from the join (without the DISTINCT) and then 'test' to see if you already have the distinct columns in the table before adding a new row?  The target table would need appropriate indexes, but I would think there wouldn't be a need for the sort either.

Comment: I removed the 30 dregree and it stops to consume temp tablespace. Now it is using 95 workers, it's normal?